# How to convert python JSON list to dataframe columns without looping

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I'm using python and trying to figure out how to do the following without using a loop.

I have a dataframe that has several columns including one that has a JSON objects list.
What I'm trying to do is convert the JSON string column into their own columns within the dataframe.
For example I have the following dataframe:

| name | age | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 35 | [{"testid": "001", "marks": 67}, {"testid": "002", "marks": 70}] |
| Ann | 20 | [{"testid": "001", "marks": 75}, {"testid": "002", "marks": 80}, {"testid": "003", "marks": 87}] |
| Emma | 25 | [{"testid": "001", "marks": 90}, {"testid": "002", "marks": 99}] |

I want to get marks for testid = 001 and testid = 002 as follows.

| name | age | test_id1 | test_id2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 35 | 67 | 70 |
| Ann | 20 | 75 | 80 |
| Emma | 25 | 90 | 99 |

Here is my dataset

```js
[
   {
      "name":"John",
      "age":35,
      "group":[
         {
            "testid":"001",
            "marks":67
         },
         {
            "testid":"002",
            "marks":70
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Ann",
      "age":20,
      "group":[
         {
            "testid":"001",
            "marks":75
         },
         {
            "testid":"002",
            "marks":80
         },
         {
            "testid":"003",
            "marks":87
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Emma",
      "age":25,
      "group":[
         {
            "testid":"001",
            "marks":90
         },
         {
            "testid":"002",
            "marks":99
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Any idea is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Kindly share the dataframe as code : ``df.to_dict('records')``

Comment: @sammywemmy Thank you for your comment. I'have added the data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list compreshension is handy here in pulling the data out; as a side note, if you can, possibly do the extraction, before getting the dict like data into a dataframe (more efficient to do so):

```
outcome = [[entry[num]['marks']
           for num in range(len(entry)) 
           if entry[num]['testid'] in ('001', '002')] 
           for entry in df.group]

print(outcome)
[[67, 70], [75, 80], [90, 99]]
```

Zip the data, and assign to new column names in the dataframe:

```
test_id1, test_id2 = zip(*outcome)

df.filter(['name', 'age']).assign(test_id1 = test_id1, test_id2 = test_id2)

   name  age  test_id1  test_id2
0  John   35        67        70
1   Ann   20        75        80
2  Emma   25        90        99
```

Comment: Thank you. 
BTW, it throws me the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//HOME-SVR-001/User Directory Folder/Administrator/Desktop/testtest.py", line 27, in <module>
    for entry in df.group]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'
Any idea?

Comment: No idea. `df` is a dataframe right? It seems your code is reading `df` as a list

Answer (score 1):

See comments inline. Using `apply()` does the iterating for you. You just need to write the function.

```
data='''name|age|group
John|35|[{"testid": "001", "marks": 67}, {"testid": "002", "marks": 70}]
Ann|20|[{"testid": "001", "marks": 75}, {"testid": "002", "marks": 80}, {"testid": "003", "marks": 87}]
Emma|25|[{"testid": "001", "marks": 90}, {"testid": "002", "marks": 99}]'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='|', engine='python')

# create function for apply()
def expand_json(xname, x):
    for i, j in enumerate(json.loads(x), 1):
        # print(i, j)
        col = 'test_id'+str(i)
        # print(col)
        # print(j['marks'])
        df.loc[df.name==xname, col] = j['marks']
        
#dftemp is a throw away so nothing prints to the screen. The function writes to the main df

dftemp = df.apply(lambda x: expand_json(x['name'], x['group']), axis=1)
print(df)

   name  age                                                                                             group  test_id1  test_id2  test_id3
0  John   35                                  [{"testid": "001", "marks": 67}, {"testid": "002", "marks": 70}]    67.000    70.000       NaN
1   Ann   20  [{"testid": "001", "marks": 75}, {"testid": "002", "marks": 80}, {"testid": "003", "marks": 87}]    75.000    80.000    87.000
2  Emma   25                                  [{"testid": "001", "marks": 90}, {"testid": "002", "marks": 99}]    90.000    99.000       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
It works.
Can I only get name, age, test_id1 and test_id2 data only

Comment: Thanks!
 I can use df.filter() function.

Comment: On the for loop in the function you can also limit it by using [0:2]. That should limit to just first two ids. Or filter as you mention.